# Full-screen Edit box

Tags: feature-request, editor

When adding / editing answers on Stack Overflow, it would be useful to be able to view the editor in fullscreen mode with a toolbar at  the top or bottom, but with the textarea maximised. Initially I sent an email to the Stack Overflow admins via the `contact-us` page and was told to address this question here.

Comment: cross-site duplicate/related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/259033/can-we-have-a-button-that-makes-the-answer-box-full-screen

Answer (score 3):

This is unlikely to be implemented, due in part to the amount of dev time it would take to add something that, to most people, would be only a minor convenience.

You can, however, use third-party Markdown editors. I like to copy the markdown of a post into [StackEdit](https://stackedit.io/editor), make whatever changes I want, then copy it back.

Comment: Never heard of that before, awesome tool.